# The Launch file could not launch in the package rbx1_nav?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I run the command in the different terminal :

```
roslaunch rbx1_bringup fake_turtlebot.launch
rosrun rviz rviz -d `rospack find rbx1_nav`/sim.rviz
rosrun rbx1_nav timed_out_and_back.py
```

it works good,but the fellow command have some problems:

```
roslaunch rbx1_nav keyboard_teleop.launch
```

it gives these message:

```
SUMMARY
========
PARAMETERS
* /rosdistro: indigo
* /rosversion: 1.11.20
* /turtlebot_teleop_keyboard/scale_angular: 0.4
* /turtlebot_teleop_keyboard/scale_linear: 0.1
NODES
turtlebot_teleop_keyboard (turtlebot_teleop/turtlebot_teleop_key)
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
core service [/rosout] found
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [turtlebot_teleop/turtlebot_teleop_key]: turtlebot_teleop
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/wangfang/catkin_ws/src/rbx1
ROS path [2]=/home/wangfang/catkin_ws/src
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
No processes to monitor
shutting down processing monitor...
```

I haven't modify the package.

anyone can tell me where the problems are? I am a freshman in ROS , Thank you verymuch.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243971/the-launch-file-could-not-launch-in-the-package-rbx1_nav-!/) by [w_fly](https://answers.ros.org/users/28017/w_fly/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [turtlebot_teleop/turtlebot_teleop_key]: turtlebot_teleop

Do you have turtlebot_teleop package?
Try to run

```
rospack find turtlebot_teleop
```

and see whether you have it or not.

If no , then you need to install it first. turtlebot_teleop is a part of turtlebot stack.

For example, if your distro is Indigo. You can follow this [link](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Turtlebot%20Installation) for installation.
Let me quote from the link :

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-turtlebot ros-indigo-turtlebot-apps ros-indigo-turtlebot-interactions ros-indigo-turtlebot-simulator ros-indigo-kobuki-ftdi ros-indigo-rocon-remocon ros-indigo-rocon-qt-library ros-indigo-ar-track-alvar-msgs
```

---

Originally posted by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) with karma: 582 on 2016-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1